# Delete duplicate records compare 5 columns in table

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns, delete-row

I have table_a. This table contains columns are,
Col1,col2,col3,col4,co5,col6,col7.

I need to delete duplicate records of col1 to col5.

I mean,

```
I'd.     Col1  col2    col3    col4   col5
-------  ----  ----    ----    ----   ----

1.        A.    B.      C.       D.    E
2.        B.    D.      R.       Y.    U
3.        A.    B.      C.       D.    E
4.        A.    B.      C.       D.    E
5.        W.    E.      R.       T.    Y
6.        W.    E.      R.       T.    Y
```

I want result id is only 1,2,5

Anybody know to design the MySQL query  please paste the solution here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT MIN(id), col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
FROM `table_a`
GROUP BY col1,col2,col3,col4,col5;
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use this query to delete duplicate records

DELETE FROM table_a WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table_a GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) LIMIT 1

this return your answer

Comment: Have you used such a query? Does it work in MySQL?